# MongoDB - Is it possible to write several different functions in MapReduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

As part of my studies, we recently started learning MongoDB, and so I am very young in the field.
In one of the tasks we have been assigned to, MapReduce is used, but I can not do it properly.

Giving a collection of students of the following form:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("4ffmdjd8cfd99k03"),
tz: "11111",
FirstName: "Anton",
LastName: "Gill",
Department: "Computer Science"
Year: 1
Courses: [ { name: "Linear Algebra 1", grade: 70}, {name: "OS", grade: 88}]
}
```

The task is to write a mapReduce function, so that it returns a list of the names of the students in each department and each year, all whose grades are greater than 90. Example of normal output:

```
[{Department: "Computer Science", Year: 1, students: ["Anton", "John"]},
{Department: "Physics", Year: 2, students: ["Dean", "David"]}]
```

Can I write more than one map function? That is, the mapReduce structure will look like this:

```
db.students.mapReduce(
    map1,
    map2,
    map3,
    ..
    reduce,
..
```

I try unsuccessfully to create the desired structure.
This is the best I've been able to get to, and I'm still not sure how to write the reduce function.

```
var map = function(){
    var value = 0, n = this.Courses.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        value += this.Courses[i].grade;
    }
    var avgGrade = value/n;
    if(avgGrade > 90){
        var key = {
        tz:this.tz,
        Department:this.Department,
        Year:this.Year,
        };
        value = {students:[this.FirstName]};
    }
    emit(key, value);
};

var reduce = function(keysObj, valuesObj){
    return 1000; //Ignore this function, I've no idea how to deal with it.
};

db.students.mapReduce(
    map,
    reduce,
    {
    out: "output",
    }
)
```

I would highly appreciate any assistance :)

Comment: Your Map output seems fine, now you just have to use the Reducer to loop over all the names for each key and format it in the correct way. Study the Word Count example to understand how Reducers work; yours won't be very different.

Comment: I still struggle with the answer and can not find a solution for her.
Can you give direction / source for assistance?